# List always empty , but i already get the respond data Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

[image]im trying to get data from web api and then store the respond json to my list. But i dont know why my list is always empty. eventhought my respond is not null, i already follow the tutorial on the internet but i don't know why i can't make this work. 
My RestService Code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


/*
  Generated class for the RestProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
  }
  searchMovies() {
    var url = 'http://192.168.0.112:44444/api/prgetlist ';
    var body = {
      "parmClaimsUser" :"ClaimGuy@MyApp.com",
      "parmCompany" :"APU"
    } 
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    var response = this.http.post(url,body, options ).map(res => res.json());
    return response;
}    
}
```

my Page Code

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http/src/client"
import {Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {RestProvider} from '../../providers/rest/rest'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
 selector:'person-home',
 templateUrl: 'person.html'
})

 export class PersonPage{
    name : any;
     constructor(public http: Http, private restprovider: RestProvider){

     }
     ionViewWillEnter(){
       this.restprovider.searchMovies().subscribe(
          data => {

              this.name = JSON.stringify(data);
              let names = JSON.stringify(data);
              alert(names);
          },
          err => {
              alert(err)
          }
       );
     }

 }
```

My HTML

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            Person
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <ion-list inset *ngFor="let data of item">\
        <ion-item>
                <h2>{{name.parmPurchReqId}}</h2>
                <p>{{name.parmPurchReqName}}</p>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

i don't know why it's not working, i've been looking this in the internet like 10 hours but the result still same. Can you review my code here and tell me why its not working , Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable name is wrong.  you are using variable as `name`

```
this.name = JSON.stringify(data);// please remove JSON.stringify as well.
```

but you are using variable in ngFor as `item`. That's a problem.

So try this below code instead of yours..

```
  <ion-list inset *ngFor="let data of name">
    <ion-item>
            <h2>{{data.parmPurchReqId}}</h2>
            <p>{{data.parmPurchReqName}}</p>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Could you please let me know the down vote?? please check my edited history before posting your down vote?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
<ion-list inset *ngFor="let data of name">
    <ion-item>
            <h2>{{data.parmPurchReqId}}</h2>
            <p>{{data.parmPurchReqName}}</p>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Duplicated answer.